# Recognizing redirect links in Selenium Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, url, web-scraping

My code currently parses through a website and sees if any of the links on the website link back to a different user-inputted website. However, on certain websites, there are links that redirect to the user-inputted website indirectly.

For example, if I'm looking for McDonalds, on Yelp the link to the McDonalds website is

https://www.yelp.com/biz_redir?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mcdonalds.com%2Fus%2Fen-us%2Fbig-mac-trio.html%3Fcid%3DPS%3AGCM_MOP%3ANB%3A%3AYelp%3AAll&website_link_type=website&src_bizid=QjISg1yoC-NAgtK_FIMynA&cachebuster=1530033657&s=d20e56f50c3e547682eb388c95d45065502248fb9116df313e2d6ee078f1ce48

while my program is looking for www.mcdonalds.com.

Another example would be bit.ly links that indirectly redirect to the website.

Here's my code for reference

```
ef search(web):
#Clicks on the site
site = web.get_attribute("href")
driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
driver.get(site)

#Wait until the webpage has loaded
try:
    start = datetime.now()
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "body")))

    #Gets the parsed url
    parsed_uri = urlparse(driver.current_url)
    domain = strip('{uri.scheme}://{uri.netloc}/'.format(uri=parsed_uri))
    #If it's taking too long, say it didn't load
    if(tooLong(start, datetime.now())):
        driver.execute_script("window.close('');")
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
        return site + " could not load"
    #If it's the same website, return nothing to add to the list
    if domain == URL:
        driver.execute_script("window.close('');")
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
        return ''
    #Else, search all links for the desired website
    else:
        elems = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
        for i in elems:
            newURI = urlparse(i.get_attribute("href"))
            check = strip('{uri.scheme}://{uri.netloc}/'.format(uri=newURI))
            print(check)
            #If it links back to the website, return nothing to add to the list
            if check == URL:
                driver.execute_script("window.close('');")
                driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
                return ''
            #If it's taking too long, say it couldn't load
            if(tooLong(start, datetime.now())):
                driver.execute_script("window.close('');")
                driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
                return site + " could not load"
    #If nothing is found, return the name of the website
    driver.execute_script("window.close('');")
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
    return site
#If the website doesn't load, flag it
except TimeoutException as ex:
    driver.execute_script("window.close('');")
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
    return site + " could not load"
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: So what is the issue in your existing code?

Comment: The issue is that for redirect links like bit.ly it doesn't work

Comment: Sorry but your code is bit hard to understand right away, wouldn't the `bit.ly` url also redirect automatically? Also if you are navigating such urls and then you would need to navigate and see what is the new url that browser has